# cant download a blob video

Tags: video, download-manager, file-download, jdownloader

i am trying to download a video from a site. i looked up for solutions online apparently its a blob video i have seen people downloading blob videos from youtube as m3u8 file with jdownloader but here i cant find its m3u8 file or anything in the media in developer tools or nothing in search for mp4 in the source i subscribed on this site and still cant download it
blob link : blob:https://www.gameleap.com/859b65e8-2525-4e6e-8aca-33beb86a122c
actual link : [https://www.gameleap.com/dota/course/randoming-to-6k-mmr~crs__5wvuJ2K0/randoming-to-6k-beastmaster~vguide_SwRUTBDbq](https://www.gameleap.com/dota/course/randoming-to-6k-mmr%7Ecrs__5wvuJ2K0/randoming-to-6k-beastmaster%7Evguide_SwRUTBDbq)

Comment: Blobs are in-memory objects. You can’t “download” them.

Comment: is there any other way i could download this video?

Comment: If the site wished to allow viewers to download the videos they would provide links and mechanisms to do this, because the site has not provided anything like this, we presume that what you're trying to do is against the wishes of the site.